# Attribute Error for pytorch_forecasting models

Tags: time-series, attributeerror, pytorch-forecasting

I'm currently trying to set up a `TemporalFusionTransformer` from the pytorch_forecasting library in Google Colab, following the exact approach that is stated [here](https://pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html).

For some reason, I always get `"AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'"` when trying to set up a model.

Even if I just try initializing a default model in the Baseline class, I get the same error (see screenshot).
[Error message for Baseline model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/els2N.png)
Maybe someone knows how to solve this issue here. Thanks in advance.

What I tried so far:

- converted my data into a `TimeSeriesDataSet` object
- used `TemporalFusionTransformer.from_dataset(...)` providing my data as well as some training parameters
- tried the same without providing the training parameters
- tried setting up the TFT with and without training parameters (i.e. `TemporalFusionTransformer(...)`)
- tried the same with the Baseline model (`Baseline()`)

result was an `Attribute error` in all cases

Answer (score 0):

pytorch_lightning had an update (https://pypi.org/project/pytorch-lightning/#history). Downgrading to version 1.9.0 worked for me.

you can use `pip install pytorch_lightning==1.9.0`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).